# How to convert list of ints into list of lists?

Tags: python, list

The problem is: how to convert properly (in "pythonic way") list of ints: `[1, 3, 7, 6]` into corresponding list of lists: `[[1], [3], [7], [6]]` with ints inside of them?

Tried to do it like: `unsorted_list = [list(str(x)) for x in unsorted_list]` but get `[['1'], ['3'], ['7'], ['6']]`. Don't know how to perform the same on ints, they are not iterable. Using `for` afterwards can solve the problem, but not so elegant.
Thank you.

Comment: @metatoaster This way it's working, thank you.

Comment: `unsorted_list = [[x] for x in unsorted_list]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't transform the integers to strings. Simply:

```
[[x] for x in unsorted_list]
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks rather logical

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach, using `map`:

```
map(lambda x: [x], unsorted_list)
```

Answer (score -2):

us like this

```
unsorted_list = [[x] for x in unsorted_list]
```

or you can use:

```
unsorted_list = map(lambda x:[x], unsorted_list)
```

Comment: Same thing: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.